# How to update the records in a table based on comparing with the id column from another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-update

Both the tables (`Table1`, `Table2`) has id columns (`T1id`, `T2id`)

From `Table1`, I am selecting some records based on condition(used `where` clause). Now, I will have some records which will have `ids`.

My goal is to `Update` those selected records for the `ids` (`T1id column` in `Table1`) which are not present in the `ids` (`T2id column` in `Table2`)

I tried the following `query`.

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Table1]  
     SET  
     Number = '', StartDate = NULL  
     WHERE
     T1id IN(SELECT T1id FROM [dbo].[Table1] WHERE DATEDIFF(hour, StartDate, DATEADD(MINUTE, 330, GETUTCDATE())) > 7)
```

How to include the `T2id column` of `Table2` for comparing with `T1id column` of `Table1` and **update only the records of Table1** if `T1id` is not present in `T2id` in the above `query`? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use joins in an update statement, so you can do something like this :

```
UPDATE  T1
     SET  
     Number = '', StartDate = NULL 
FROM [dbo].[Table1] T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.id = T2.id
     WHERE T2.id IS NULL 
     AND  DATEDIFF(hour, T1.StartDate, DATEADD(MINUTE, 330, GETUTCDATE())) > 7)
```

Answer (score 0):

USE Except operator while checking for ID in other table(Table 2):

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Table1]
SET    Number = '',
       StartDate = NULL
WHERE  T1id IN(SELECT T1id
               FROM   [dbo].[Table1]
               --WHERE  Datediff(hour, StartDate, Dateadd(MINUTE, 330, Getutcdate())) > 7) <--Your where cond goes here. 
               EXCEPT
               SELECT T2id
               FROM   [dbo].[Table2])
```